# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'to' while training QuestionAnsweringModel from simpletransformers

Tags: python, nlp, nlp-question-answering, simpletransformers

I'm trying to train QuestionAnsweringModel bert-base-multilingual-uncased from simpletransformers and faced next problem:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-40e9356ccee6> in <module>()
----> 1 model.train(traindata, output_dir='/content/drive/MyDrive')

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/simpletransformers/question_answering/question_answering_model.py in train(self, train_dataset, output_dir, show_running_loss, eval_data, verbose, **kwargs)
    578                     steps_trained_in_current_epoch -= 1
    579                     continue
--> 580                 batch = tuple(t.to(device) for t in batch)
    581 
    582                 inputs = self._get_inputs_dict(batch)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/simpletransformers/question_answering/question_answering_model.py in <genexpr>(.0)
    578                     steps_trained_in_current_epoch -= 1
    579                     continue
--> 580                 batch = tuple(t.to(device) for t in batch)
    581 
    582                 inputs = self._get_inputs_dict(batch)

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'to'
```

My data prepairing:

```
!wget https://onti2020.ai-academy.ru/task/rucos_test.jsonl
!wget https://onti2020.ai-academy.ru/task/rucos_val.jsonl
!wget https://onti2020.ai-academy.ru/task/rucos_train.jsonl.zip
!unzip rucos_train.jsonl.zip
```

```
!pip install nltk
import nltk
nltk.download('all')
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
```

```
def get_train_data(jsonfile):
    res=[]
    with open(jsonfile, 'r') as data:
        trainlist=list(data)
        for item in tqdm(trainlist):
            item=json.loads(item)
            dictt={}
            dictt['context']=word_tokenize(item['passage']['text'])
            qas=[]
            qlist=item['qas']
            for q in qlist:
                qdict={}
                qdict['id']=str(q['idx']).rjust(6, '0')
                answers=[]
                qdict['is_impossible']=True
                qdict['question']=q['query']
                alist=q['answers']
                for a in alist:
                    adict={}
                    adict['text']=a['text']
                    adict['answer_start']=a['start']
                    answers.append(adict)
                qdict['answers']=answers
                qas.append(qdict)
            dictt['qas']=qas
            res.append(dictt)
    return res
```

```
traindata, evaldata=get_train_data('rucos_train.jsonl'), get_train_data('rucos_val.jsonl')
```

Model building:

```
!pip install simpletransformers
!pip install torch==1.5.0
```

```
from simpletransformers.question_answering import QuestionAnsweringModel, QuestionAnsweringArgs
model = QuestionAnsweringModel(
    "bert",
    "bert-base-multilingual-uncased",
    args=QuestionAnsweringArgs(n_best_size=2)
)
```

Model training:

```
model.train(traindata, output_dir='/content/drive/MyDrive')
```

This code was executing in Colab Pro and based on documentation https://simpletransformers.ai/docs/qa-model/.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: You have not tokenized the text?

Comment: Thanks. How to do this?

Comment: @AshwinGeetD'Sa, so I have tokenized the text and edited this question. But i'm getting the same error.

Comment: Sorry, I had assumed that you were using huggingface transformers. This seems more like the problem of API.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use train_model function instead of train function.

```
model.train_model(traindata)
```

Hope this answer isn't too late.